# vpn/Openvpn as a cloud service

Tags: vpn, amazon-ec2, openvpn, cloud-computing, certificate-authority

I am working on creating a small cloud (any number of EC2 instances that can be deployed based on load) implementing a VPN as a service for the company I'm working for. This is basically a project gathering together various vpn resources under one aegis as a cloud based service.

As a user of openvpn, I'm somewhat familiar with being able to connect, but I'm looking for resources to start this project. 
   Essentially I need to be able to:

- run a certificate authority and manage keys to distribute to coworkers
- build an ami that handles openvpn as a service
- balance the load if necessary among machines instances as needed

Any suggestions for tutorials, things to avoid, roadblocks I might not be seeing from a novice perspective, etc. or just help in visualizing this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to create a secure channel between your enterprise and the cloud. You can try Virtual Private Cloud which is  offered by Amazon [VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/). By this way, you will extend your existing management capabilities such as security services, firewalls, and intrusion detection systems to include their AWS resources.

if it does not answer your questions, look at this [document](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/) to get high level idea.